# SQL Query - Returning Multiple Detail Rows

Tags: sql, one-to-many

I have two tables `HHHORDHP` (invoice header data) and `HHIORDDP` (invoice detail data).

I want to return a row with header data and then the detail line items for that invoice followed by the next header row and then its detail records, etc.

I would filter by customer and invoice date. Do I need a subquery to accomplish this? I am not an advanced SQL user and am looking for any help in how to accomplish this.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I have read through past postings and am not able to find a solution, I have tried a union all but that doesn't look right and I get all header records first and then all detail records. Can anyone point we in the right direction as to the construct needed?

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to separate your thinking into two phases: data retrieval and report formatting.

For the data retrieval portion, you would perform a `JOIN` of the tables on some shared key - most likely an invoice number. The result set would contain one row for each of the detail records, and each of those detail rows would contain all of the related header information.

You would then need to instruct your reporting layer to format that result set in the way you describe.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have no reporting layer, the result set will be sent t client whose system will ingest it so I need to follow their format which requires a separate header row for each invoice.